# Variable Product Price - Change Display Location

Tags: plugins

I've built a custom theme for a Woocommerce shop and changed the custom product price front its default location to another.

This works well with single products, or variable products with the same price between variations.

However, when viewing a variable price product, I get two price tags displayed, istead of just updating the existing one.

Example
[image]

I've tried a jquery approach to update the upper field and hide the other, but it just doens't feel to be the right approach.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look at my answers [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115097/22534) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/117427/22534) to solve your problem.

Comment: I tried them all but they don't work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong? I did as you answered in the first link, but it just changes the order of the appearance of the price which is in the correct place. What I want is to either, on select, update the first price ("Desde: 9€"), or to be able to place it in other part of the template...